# increment firebase field value in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with that code below.

I want to create a blog app and I want to let people like posts and when someone clicks the like button it

should increase the field value in firebase and if he clicked again it decrements the value.

My Code : -

```dart
bool liked = false;

------------------

onPressed: () async {
          await Firestore.instance
              .collection('posts')
              .document('${widget.uid}')
              .updateData(
            {
              "likes": FieldValue.increment(
                (liked ? (-1) : (1)),
              ),
            },
          );
          setState(() {
            liked = !liked;
          });
        },
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? What does it do when you run it?

Comment: the likes increase only

Comment: That sounds like `liked` is always `false.. Did you check if the state actually gets changed when you call `setState`?

Comment: yes I've checked

Comment: If possible can you add your full code.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your `liked` value go back to false even after the setState. Did you check `liked` before updating data. And could you show us exactly where do you declare your variable.

Comment: exactly as you've said and I'll try to solve this with shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it  just seems like everytime you click the value of 'liked' is false. That makes your code to just increment the value by one. You have to check if the user has liked the post before and then change the state for the 'liked' bool.